# Why is pageContext.request.contextPath interpreted as $%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm writing a simple REST based Spring MVC app using pure Java Configuration. I've written many applications before and never have I faced this issue.
My url `<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/test/hello">Hello</a>`
is interpreted as 
  `$%7BpageContext.request.contextPath%7D/test/hello`

On researching, I found that I need to set the web-app version at 2.4+
As I'm writing a pure java config app, I was not able to change it in web.xml.
So I tried to change the Dynamic Web Module to 3.0(currently set at 2.3).
But, as many people have faced this issue, eclipse didn't allow me to change it.
So I changed it in project.facet.core.xml, but it didn't solve the url issue and also I got a new error "Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.3."
What I don't understand is if I have manually set the web module version to 3.0 in xml, why is eclipse trying to set again to 2.3?

Ufff!!! Lots of issues
I have tried to solve this problem for around 8 hours now without any success, so please any help in this matter is appreciated!

jsp file:

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<a href="mavn_spring_rest_demo/test/hello">try it </a>
</body>
</html>
```

config class:

````
```@EnableWebMvc
```@ComponentScan("com.org")
```public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{
```}

servlet initializer class:
```public class MyServletInitializerConfig extends  
```AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    ```@Override
    ```protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        ```return new Class[] { MyConfig.class };
    ```}
    ```@Override
    ```protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        ```return new String[] { "/" };
    ```}

rest controller:
```@RestController
```@RequestMapping("/test")
```public class MyRestController {
    ```@GetMapping("/hello")
    ```public String sayHello() {
           return "hello finally";
    ```}
```}
````

Comment: While it is unclear why your expression is not being resolved, I just like to suggest to write `${request.contextPath}`. No need to go through the pageContext object here.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Mick, but now it is $%7Brequest.contextPath%7D

Comment: The JSP processor seems not to kick in. Please post your full JSP source code. Especially the header lines.

Comment: @Mick updated op with complete jsp file. It was the basic one created by default, i just added my url

Answer (score 2):

You should delete your web.xml file and restart your local server, I think you and I follow the same course. I had that issue because I had a empty web.xml file. I am a newbie but when configuring just plain java classes, empty web.xml file get in the way.

Just give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem when i use `{pageContext.request.contextPath}` in my jsp file, as you said the problem is (web-app at 2.3) and i solve that by modify xml code in `web.xml`. like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
         version="3.1">
  <display-name>spring-rest-demo</display-name>
</web-app>
```

you can copy this code into your `web.xml` file,

hope this is work for your project

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following JSP Directive at the top of your jsp file:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

JSP directives are used to give special instruction to a JSP container for translation of JSP to servlet code.

Read more about JSP Directives at https://www.guru99.com/jsp-actions.html